# What exactly is the difference between "cool" and "cold"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

We usually hear "He is a cool guy" when referring to some hippie or a funky person. However the tone changes dramatically when *cool* becomes *cold*. We say "Her behaviour was cold" to mean someone who is unfriendly.

What is the exact difference between the words in different contexts, say, temperature, demeanour, etc? Why have they developed a semantic difference despite their similarity?

Comment: _Cool_ has two possible meanings in a sentence like "He's a [cool](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cool) guy". One is the standard meaning of being detached and without much obvious emotion; the other is the slang meaning of being excellent, good, or acceptable/alright/not a threat. _Cold_ in that sentence means unfriendly, ruthless, & without normal human emotion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally, *cool* meant someone who was somewhat standoffish in their demeanour, or someone who does not get too involved - and *cold* was just a more extreme form of that.

As Bill Franke points out, the meaning of *cool* meaning popular or trendy probably originated with *cool jazz* in 1945 and began being used to describe people in the 1950s seeing a rise in usage through the 1960s and a large spike in popular usage in the 1980s and 90s:

[image]

[image]

For this reason, "**he's a cool guy**" in modern English means "He is a trendy (or fashionable) person" rather than "His character is standoffish", whereas the meaning for *cold* never evolved to mean trendy, and retains its older meaning of someone who is very detached and unemotional.

If you want to use *cool* in the sense of someone who is slightly unemotional, you might prefer to use the idiom **He's a cool cat** or **He's a cool character** which both retain the old (non-trendy) meaning of the word *cool*. Alternatively you can say something like **His response was somewhat cold** as a less ambiguous alternative to **His response was cool**.

Comment: See this link about ["cool jazz"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_jazz), surely the source of of the "great, awesome" meaning. Miles Davis was the king of cool jazz, & "Chet Baker [was] known as the 'Prince of Cool'." This style came into vogue during the late 1940s & peaked in the '50s & '60s, just when [the Beats & their slang](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/slang/what-are-some-beatnik-slang-terms.html) were becoming popular. What's your source for "cool" hitting pop culture in the 1980s? See this [1963 usage](http://snurl.com/26rd67i) in _Life_ magazine.

Comment: @BillFranke: See my Ngrams. I think you're right that it probably started with cool jazz, but as you can see by the graphs, there is a big spike in the 1980s that begins to tail off in the mid 2000s.

Comment: @Matt The problem with Google Ngrams is that its underlying corpus is books. I can assure you (having been there at the time) that *cool* was applied to persons as well as music in the 50s and 60s. The 90s use was a revival of a term which had gone out of fashion among the hip in the late 60s.

Comment: @StoneyB: Fast Times at Ridgemont High (1982).

Comment: @BillFranke OK, 80s. I was out of touch with hipness after about 76, and didn't get back in touch until I had a son.

Comment: @StoneyB: Actually, I meant that Matt's historical reference point was probably _Fast Times_, but mine are Miles Davis & the Beats in the 1950s, as are yours, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: With respect to Sean Penn *et al* (who admittedly may have helped), the real 80s surge in the word imho, was due to one Arthur Fonzarelli - the coolest of the cool to this day (notwithstanding that whole shark jumping thing).

Answer (score 1):

*Cold* means, "without emotion; unfriendly"; *cool* means, "not friendly, interested or enthusiastic."
The difference is that *cold* generally means that somebody is less friendly than somebody who is cool.

*Cool* is also informally used to show approval or admiration; that is what happens in the following sentences:

> You look pretty cool with that new haircut.

> It's a cool movie.

Similar meaning is given to *cool* in the following sentence.

> **A**: We're meeting Jake for lunch and we can go on the yacht in the afternoon.
>   **B**: Cool!

Comment: What about "He is a cool guy"? Why is *cool* playing a different role there? Does *cold* accentuate *cool*'s effect in that sentence? Obviously no, but why?

Comment: Thanks Matt. Is there an answer to my second question: Why have they developed a semantic difference despite their similarity?

Comment: @Sultan: See [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_(aesthetic)) two [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_jazz).

Answer (score 1):

I am bit surprised that all the previous answers to Sultan focus on the meaning of "cool" and "cold" as first of all referring to the personality of people.

To me, as a non native speaker, "cool" and "cold" are first of all something denoting temperature. Just like "hot" (which can, similarly, also refer to personality or look).

Like a in "cool breeze", or a "cold winter".

In this case "cool" and "fresh" as closer. Cold is something more "extreme" (say, closer to 0 °C), like ice (frozen water) or close to that.   ;-)